# Firepad and CodeMirror 6

Tags: firebase, codemirror, firepad, codemirror-6

I couldn't find this information on either Firepad documentation or CodeMirror. I have read CodeMirror is npm bundle based. Is Firepad compatible with CodeMirror 6 ?

Comment: What is CodeMirror 6? CodeMirror is on [version 5.65.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror), there is no CodeMirror 6 from what I can tell.

Comment: Here is CodeMirror 6 link https://codemirror.net/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Firepad compatible with CodeMirror 6 ?

Probably not. At the time of writing, Firepad is running on 5.52.2 ([see `package.json`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad/blob/master/package.json)) and isn't actively developed anymore ([see `README.md`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad/blob/master/README.md)):

> This repository is no longer under active development. No new features will be added and issues are not actively triaged. Pull Requests which fix bugs are welcome and will be reviewed on a best-effort basis.

Since Codemirror 6 seems a complete rewrite with a new architecture, I don't think anymore will bother to port it over at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The original project is no longer mantainer, but I got it working and published the result as the npm package `@lucafabbian/firebase`. Far from perfect, but runs without major issues.

Check my demo here:

https://github.com/lucafabbian/codemirror6-firepad-demo